How to test the content and behaviour of a Ionic modal with vue-test-utils?
I am working on an app written with Vue3 and Ionic8, and I wrote a Vue component that is basically a custom modal. Now I would like to unit-test my component, but I am not able to access the content of the modal from the test code. How do I do that with vue-test-utils and vitest (because this is what we use so far)?
Let's say I have a Vue component in MyCustomModal.vue:
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  isOpen: boolean;
  userName: string;
}>();
</script>
<template>
  <ion-modal :is-open="isOpen" @did-dismiss="emit('didDismiss')">
    <div><h2>Your initial is {{ userName[0] }}</h2></div>
  </ion-modal>
</template>

Now I would like to test that the component renders the initial letter of the name given as prop, so I thought I can write a spec like so:
describe("MyCustomModal", () => {
  it("should display the title with the name initial", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyCustomModal, {
      props: {
        isOpen: true,
        userName: "John Doe",
      },
    });

    expect(wrapper.element.isOpen).toBe(true);
    //Pass

    console.log(wrapper.text());
    //Prints an empty string
    console.log(wrapper.html());
    //Prints <ion-modal data-v-30836913=""></ion-modal>

    expect(wrapper.find("h2").text()).toContain("Your initial is J");
    //Error: Cannot call text on an empty DOMWrapper.
  });
});

What am I missing to be able to inspect the content of the modal, and for example trigger events to test the behaviour (e.g. wrapper.find("button").trigger("click"))?
I found this similar question, but it is for Angular and a very old version of Ionic.

Provide a mock that processes is-open and did-dismiss according to your expectations. With unit tests it's as simple as that

I don't understand. I want to check that my component renders the initial of the provided name, how can I do that if I mock the modal? I think what you describe would be to test another component that uses MyCustomModal.

I mean there could be a problem with test methodology, since you're explicitly after unit tests. In unit test, generally anything but tested unit is mocked. And this certainly applies to third-party libs and components. It's not your job to test them, they already have test coverage. If you want to test the thing works together, that's integration test, which isn't a replacement for unit tests. It's possible to sacrifice one test coverage in favor of another, but this needs to be balanced decision

And the problem with integration tests is that they have limited value and <100% coverage in this environment because vue-test-utils doesn't behave exactly like real framework, and jest/vitest doesn't behave like a browser at all. As a rule of thumb, I'd focus on isolated unit tests, and save testing the integrations for real browser environment where component behaviour can be reliably tested (cypress, playwright, etc). But YMMV

Technically in MyCustomModal unit test you need to test that you provided a correct name to ion-model through a slot. And then likely test that you used is-open and did-dismiss correctly. Which can be done with mocked ion-modal comp

I think I see what you mean. I'm still interested in knowing why I can't access the slot content from my test, but will give a shot to mocking the modal. Thanks!

I'm not sure what happens here.  in html means that it's processed as custom element and not rendered as a component, which makes sense. You didn't register IonModal in mount(), which you should do for an integration test. But then it was supposed to render the slot of ion-modal as is, but this didn't happen
